# How to draw a certain pyramid pattern

Tags: python

I'm trying to get these shapes:

if num=9

> ```
>         *
>       *   *
>     *       *
>   *           *
> *               *
> ```

if num=5

> ```
>     *
>   *   *
> *       *
> ```

if num=3

> ```
>   * 
> *   *
> ```

(Only odd inputs)

```
num = int(input())

for row in range(num):
    for col in range((num*2)-1):
        if row==0 and col==((num*2)-1)//2 or row==1 and (col==2 or col==6) or row==2 and (col==0 or col==8):
            print('*', end='')
        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

This is what I managed to write but the code is hardcoded to draw a pyramid of 5 stars, so giving it any other input would mess the shape

[image]

I got column and row from a quick sketch
based on this image

I would like to automate the code so any input I feed it, it would draw this specific pyramid shape. I need help, thank you.

Comment: What about even inputs, like 2, 4, 6 ...etc.

Comment: Only odd inputs

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217288/rhombus-shape-based-on-user-input/51219021

Comment: Shouldn't it start with `for row in range(num//2 + 1):`? `num` is the number of columns, not the number of rows.

Comment: also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205442/how-to-print-diamond-shape-pattern-in-c/63205683#63205683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start thinking about how different properties relate to the input number, and make a variable for each one. Start with how many rows, and how many columns. Then think of an equation that can give you the star location based on the current column and row. This should be easy to determine from the diagram you posted.

```
num = int(input())

num_rows = (num // 2) + 1
num_cols = (num * 2) - 1
middle_col = num - 1

for row_index in range(num_rows):
    left_star_col = middle_col - (2 * row_index)
    right_star_col = middle_col + (2 * row_index)

    for col_index in range(num_cols):
        if col_index == left_star_col or col_index == right_star_col:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print()  # newline
```

Comment: Wow, I am forever grateful for your answer. I'm starting out with python for loops and it's a bit confusing. I've just unlocked a new perception in drawing out patterns using for loops thanks to your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Anony Absolutely. My mantra when writing code is that it should be simple and easy to read. Start with the easy questions you can answer and work your way up. Sure you could write this in fewer lines, but having code that is easy to understand is important (especially if you come back to it months later). Good luck and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with a helper list. For each row, place a star i steps left of the middle and i steps right of the middle:

```
half = num // 2
for i in range(half + 1):
    row = [' '] * num
    row[half-i] = row[half+i] = '*'
    print(*row)
```

Output for `num = 9` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P680V8FWwZKLKyMxJw3IAvH19RWMuNLyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNcDS2gqGmlZcCkBQlF8OVBytrqAeq6AF0gQTjQYp1M2MBcrCeNpgnrqWOlhNQVFmXomGFlBS8/9/AA)):

```
        *        
      *   *      
    *       *    
  *           *  
*               *
```

It prints a few spaces at the end of the upper lines. If that's troublesome, make the row just as long as needed:

```
half = num // 2
for i in range(half + 1):
    row = [' '] * (half + i + 1)
    row[half-i] = row[half+i] = '*'
    print(*row)
```

If you replace the `' '` with `'-'`, you can see more what's happening:

```
- - - - *
- - - * - *
- - * - - - *
- * - - - - - *
* - - - - - - - *
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the output very close what you desire. When you run you may see the first '*' little bit off to the left, but you can adjust for that.

```
def pyramid(n):
    ll = []
    ct = 0
    for row in range(n//2, -1, -1):
        l = [''] * n
        l[row] = '*'
        l[row + ct] = '*'
        ct += 2
        ll.append(l)
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in ll))
```

With minor adjustment, below should give you exactly what you need.

```
def pyramid(n):
    ll = []
    ct = 0
    for row in range(n//2, -1, -1):
        l = [''] * n
        l[row] = '*'
        l[row + ct] = '*'
        ct += 2
        ll.append(l)
        l.insert(n//2, '')
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in ll))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define the pyramid shape as a graph: of the form `y = abs(x - offset)` (interactive demo [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9pgjpmbhq1))

This can be done in python like so:

```
num = int(input())

for row in range(num // 2 + 1):
    for col in range(num * 2 - 1):
        if 2 * row == abs(num - 1 - col):
            print('*', end='')
        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `row` counter is too high, since `num` is the number of columns.

It's simpler if you treat row 0 specially, since it only has one `*` rather than 2.

Rather than looping over columns, calculate the number of spaces you need and print that many spaces using `" " * count`

```
for row in range(num//2 + 1):
    if row == 0:
        print(("  " * (num//2)) + "*")
    else:
        print(("  " * (num//2 - row)) + "*" + (" " * (row*4 - 1)) + "*")
```

Comment: You have to double the blank spaces at the start of each line: " "*(num-1-2*row)

Comment: I achieved that by using two spaces in the string.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that it was two characters long

Comment: It wasn't originally, that was part of the edit.